# Is it possible to include values from Registration Form in admin notification email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When a new WooCommerce customer registers I am using this code to send an email to admin to notify them:

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'admin_email_on_registration', 10 , 1);
function admin_email_on_registration( $customer_id) {
    wp_new_user_notification( $customer_id );
}
```

I have also found this code to customise the email:

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email_admin', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {

$wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] New user %s registered.', $blogname, $user->user_login );
$wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = sprintf( "%s ( %s ) has registerd to your website %s.", $user->user_login, $user->user_email, $blogname );

return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Is it possible to add all the values from the registration form to this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible, try it and ask here if you found issue.

Comment: Do you know how to do it??

Comment: is your problem resolved? also what you want to add here ? what fields you require to add ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add all the values from the registration form to this?

According to above, registration fields supposed to be first name, last name, nick name etc, so assuming this all the above data stored in user-meta table in wordpress so you need to get user meta.
Thats how you can get, where **9** is the **user id**

```
<?php
  $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( 9 );
  print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
?>
```

Result would be like

```
Array ( 
    [first_name] => Array ( [0] => Tom ) 
    [last_name] => Array ( [0] => Auger) 
    [nickname] => Array ( [0] => tomauger ) 
    [description] => etc.... 
)
```

So in your function you need to add above 2 line and read the value one by one from array using `first name` as index of returned array

Updated function.

```
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {

    $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
    // print_r( $all_meta_for_user ); // remove '//' for debug.

    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] New user %s registered.', $blogname, $user->user_login );
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = sprintf( "%s ( %s ) has registerd to your website %s.", $user->user_login, $user->user_email, $blogname );
    // getting value from $all_meta_for_user
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['firtname'] = sprintf( "%s", $all_meta_for_user['firt name'] );

    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, I seem to get an empty array.

Comment: @MichelleBritton try `print_r($user);` what you get ?